# Getting page title in page layout

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, page-layout, spcontext

I am using the following code to get page title of current page in Page Layout but it is not working.

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" text="<%$SPContext.Current.Item['Title']%>"></asp:Literal>
```

How to get page title in page layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working on the client, no matter how mysteriously the HTML page's title was originally composed (if that's what you want):

```
<html>
  ...
  The title of the document is:
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(document.title);
  </script>
  ...
</html>
```

see: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_title.asp

Comment: `document.title` prints the space - page name here. I use `<script>document.write(document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_wikiPageNameDisplay").innerHTML);</script>`

Answer (score 0):

What you need us the `SharePointWebControl:TextField` or `SharePointWebControl:FieldProperty` control.

Waldek has written a blog about it here: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/showing-names-site-columns-page-layout/#

Comment: Ok I will have a look at it tomorrow morning.